# Efficient Implementation of a Notification System -- Should I use or avoid JOINs?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

### The Tables

Let us assume that we have a table of articles:

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
    id      integer PRIMARY KEY,

    last_update timestamp NOT NULL,

    ...
);
```

Users can bookmark articles:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmarks
(

    user        integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    article     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES articles(id),

    PRIMARY KEY(user, article),

    last_seen   timestamp NOT NULL

);
```

### The Feature to be Implemented

What I want to do now is to inform users about articles which have been updated *after* the user has last seen them. The access to the whole system is via a web interface. Whenever a page is requested, the system should check whether the user should be notified about updated articles (similar to the notification bar on the top of a page here on SO).

### The Question

What is the best and most efficient implementation of such a feature, given that both tables above contain tens of millions of rows?

### My Solution #1

One could do a simple join like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM articles, bookmarks WHERE bookmarks.user = 1234
AND bookmarks.article = articles.article AND last_seen < last_update;
```

However, I'm worried that doing this JOIN might be expensive if the user has many bookmarked articles (which might happen more often than you think), especially if the database (in my case PostgreSQL) has to traverse the index on the primary key of `articles` for every bookmarked article. Also the `last_seen < last_update` predicate can only be checked after accessing the rows on the disk.

### My Solution #2

Another method is more difficult, but might be better in my case. It involves expanding the bookmarks table by a notify column:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmarks
(

    user        integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
    article     integer NOT NULL REFERENCES articles(id),

    PRIMARY KEY(user, article),

    last_seen   timestamp NOT NULL,

    notify      boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false

);

CREATE INDEX bookmark_article_idx ON bookmarks (article);
```

Whenever an article is updated, the update operation should trigger setting notify to true for every user who has bookmarked this article. The big disadvantage that comes to mind is that if an article has been bookmarked a lot, setting notify to true for lots of rows can be expensive. The advantage could be that checking for notifications is as simple as:

```
SELECT article FROM bookmarks WHERE user = 1234 AND notify = true;
```

### Final Thoughts

I think that the second method can be a lot more efficient if the number of page views (and with it the number of times the system checks for notifications) outweighs the number of updates of articles. However, this might not always be the case. There might be users with lots of bookmarked articles which log in only once a month for a couple of minutes, and others who check for updates almost every minute.

There's also a third method that involves a notification table in which the system INSERTs notifications for every user once an article is updated. However, I consider that an inefficient variant of Method #2 since it involves saving notifications.

What method is the most efficient when both tables contain millions of rows? Do you have another method that might be better?

Comment: These tables are small enough that testing both designs with random data is practical. Build both, and test with [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html).

Comment: "Joins are expensive" is mostly a myth. The cost of traversing the index is also extremely low. +1 for Mike's suggestion: compare real performance numbers with real data in real designs or you will mislead yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly go for solution one, making sure that articles has an index on (article,last_update).

Comment: Thank you. Why would you certainly go for solution one? Should I also add an index on bookmarks(user, article, last_seen) to make sure that the last_seen < last_update predicate can be checked wholly with indexes (which hopefully fit into memory)?

Comment: It is simple, conventional, and I'd expect it to perform just as well as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization theory takes you directly to solution #1.  Rather than asking *which design is faster*, you might want to ask, *how do I make my server executes this query* efficiently given my bog-standard BCNF tables.  :-)

If your server cannot be made to execute your query fast enough (for whatever value of *enough* in your case) you need a faster server.  Why?  Because performance will only degrade as users and rows are added.  Normalization was invented to minimize updates and update anomalies.  Use it to your advantage, or pay the price in hours of your time and hard-to-detect errors in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I see a third solution, to make things more interesting. ;-) It is a mixture of both solutions. I would assume that there is a time of the day or night where little usage is on the system and make a dayly/nightly run to mark all the bookmarks that are new.

That alone would delay the information "new article updates for you!" for a day which is not what you want. But I would store an additional column "updated today" (enum "Yes", "No" or tinyint) which is set to "Yes" at article- update and reset to "No" on that nightly update-run.

Then show the "has changes" for all bookmarks with the mark "is changed" (from nightly cron) and additionally add the Information with the select from version 1, but restricted to the articles which have changed today.

Probably most articles get not updated dayly, so you should win with that.

Of course I would approve the measurement-answer, but you need a lot of assumptions to make a good benchmark.